# CodeIgniter with datamapper ORM

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am using `get()` method in data mapper to select columns from database. I am passing this object to `json_encode();` When I do this, I get this error

```
json_encode()  type is unsupported, encoded as null
```

**Update three**

```
["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"JOHN\",\"city\":\"null\"}"
,"{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"MICHEAL\,\"city\":\"null\"}"]
```

This is my response, I do not select city but still city appears. How to get json in correct format

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

```
[Break On This Error]   

var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: are you using this in a model?

Comment: @Crowlix: Thanks for taking time to anwer to my question. In my mode ,I have this code class Tag extends DataMapper{ }.Should I inclide application/datamapper to my code igniter application folder.Can you tell me, normally , how to use get() and  pass that object to json_enocde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding a Datamapper object to a json object requires a function from an extension. You can find ways to import extensions here: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/extensions.html 
This is one way of doing it:

```
class Test extends DataMapper {

    // Include the json extension
    var $extensions = array('json');
.......

  $test= new Test();                
  $test->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
  $test->select('id,name');
  $test->get();
  $test->set_json_content_type();
  echo $test->all_to_json();
```

The fact that the 'city' column is there is normal. From the DataMapper user guide:

> The object is populated with all objects from its corresponding table,
>   but with only the title and description fields populated

To decode your JSON, you need to use this method (don't forget to import the extension if you haven't already)

```
$n = new Test();
$n->from_json([put your JSON string here]);
```

Comment: :If I use, echo $test->all_to_json(); I get output with slashses in JSON. Now the problem is slash, If I remove slashes, I am good to go.

Comment: btw, you should delete some of your comments. This is getting a bit messy :p

Comment: :I have posted update three to my question, still problem exists.

Comment: :I used srt_replace() and removed all slashes but in my jquery  success fn, If  use console.log(data). Nothing is getting printed.I have not tried ur recent answer. Where should I decode, I mean, should I used it in controller. Why are you echoing both encode and decode.

Comment: :I am passing the json_encode values to my jquery ajax fn so If I use JSON.parse(data), I can get it but now why is it not passing to my jqery ajax fn

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Datamapper for CI, but I'm pretty sure you should be doing the following:

```
$test= new Test();                
$test->select('id,tag_name');
$test->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
$test->get();
json_encode($test);
```

Note: calling ->get() should be last call, before you use the $test variable to JSON encode it.